# Type mismsatch can not convert from float to Boolean

Tags: java, type-mismatch

I am very new in Java and having what I'm sure is a logic problem with this program. The idea is to create a program that loops and provides the area of a circle and the volume of a sphere. I can get the area and the volume, but I can't seem to make the program loop. When I try w/ boolean values it tells me to convert to float and vice versa. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Sphere 
{ 

private static final double radius = 0;

public static void main(String argv[]) 
{ 
    float c;
float s;
String x;

Scanner input;

System.out.print("Welcome to the round object calculator.\n This program will calculate the area       of a circle or the volume of a Sphere. \nEnter C for circle, S for sphere, or X t exit");

c = input.nextFloat();
s = input.nextFloat();
x = input.nextLine();

if (c){

    System.out.print( "Enter radius of sphere: " ); 
    float radius = input.nextFloat(); 
    break;
    }

if (s){
    System.out.println("Sphere volume is : " + ( 4.0 / 3.0 ) * Math.PI * Math.pow( radius, 3 )); 
    System.out.println("Sphere Surface Area is : " + 4.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow( radius, 3 )); 
}

if (x){
    System.out.println("End program");
}
} 
}
```

Thank you everyone for your help!I am now having another issue though in that the program is supposed to loop, once it supplies the are or volume it should ask if you want to enter another, but I can no make this work. Here is the updated code

```
 import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Sphere 
{ 

private static final double radius = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Welcome to the round object calculator.\n "
        + "This program will calculate the area      "
        + " of a circle or the volume of a Sphere. "
        + "\nEnter C for circle, S for sphere, or X t exit");
String userInput = input.next();

if ("c".equals(userInput)){

    }

if ("s".equals(userInput)){
    System.out.print( "Enter radius of sphere: " );
    float radius = input.nextFloat();


    System.out.println("Sphere volume is : " + ( 4.0 / 3.0 ) * Math.PI * Math.pow( radius, 3 )); 
    System.out.println("Sphere Surface Area is : " + 4.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow( radius, 3 )); 
    System.out.println("Enter C, S or X");

}    



if ("x".equals(userInput)){
    System.out.println("End program");
}
} 
}
```

Comment: what about the fact that you never set a value for `input`...something like `input = new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: The answer pointed out why you're getting an error, but: what were you trying to accomplish?  What did you think `if (c)` was going to do, and why is it there?

Comment: the OP probably doesnt know that `nextFloat` crashes if you dont get a float from the user

Comment: as a matter of fact it looks like the OP thinks that `input.nextFloat` and `input.nextLine()` tells you if c, s, or x was entered by the user...and the if tests to see if that is the case

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was thinking, I did add the input statement, but what would be a better way to get this to accept the input? This is where I am having all my issues?

Answer (score 2):

You if condition needs to be a boolean operation.

```
if (c)
if (s)
if (x)
```

Here c,s,x are float,float,string respectively.

The code you are trying to do is

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    String x;
    float radius;
    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) { // Starting a loop to go on till user enters x
        System.out.println(
                "Welcome to the round object calculator.\n This program will calculate the area of a circle or the volume of a Sphere. \nEnter C for circle, S for sphere, or X t exit");
        x = input.nextLine(); // Taking input from the user

        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) { // checkin is c was entered 
            System.out.print("Enter radius of circle: ");
            radius = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("Circle perimeter is : " + 2.0 * Math.PI * radius);
            System.out.println("Circle Area is : " + Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2));
        } else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) { // checkin is s was entered 
            System.out.print("Enter radius of sphere: ");
            radius = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("Sphere volume is : " + (4.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3));
            System.out.println("Sphere Surface Area is : " + 4.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3));
        } else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) { // checkin is x was entered 
            break; // leaves the loop
        }
        input.nextLine(); // eats the new line received from the nextFloat()
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can add a bit more explanation...this is a lot to digest for a new programmer...instead of showing the answer explain what each line does, since this might a homework assignment and just giving them the answer is not going to help them in their programming career

Comment: Added a few comments if i have missed out on something please feel free to edit it !

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful, I am now having another issue though in that the program is supposed to loop, once it supplies the are or volume it should ask if you want to enter another, but I can no make this work. Here is the updated code

Comment: @JavaStudent I have done that it my code ! read the comment 4 line in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your Scanner, you use floats and Strings as booleans. You have to tell the compiler what you mean with `if(c)` and `if(s)` and so on..

Did you mean something like this?:

```
public class Sphere {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .print("Welcome to the round object calculator.\n This program will calculate the area       of a circle or the volume of a Sphere. \nEnter C for circle, S for sphere, or X t exit");
        try {
            // bail out on wrong input..
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Enter radius of sphere: ");
                float radius = input.nextFloat();
                System.out.println("Sphere volume is : " + (4.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3));
                System.out.println("Sphere Surface Area is : " + 4.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3));
            }
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("End program");
    }
}
```

Comment: i believe the OP wants to detect if the user typed a c (circle), x (exit), or s (sphere) before printing any information

Comment: Seems like a reasonable guess :-)

Comment: Yes I do want it to print the circle info for C etc. I am a bit confused by this code. You have while(true), but where would I declare what is true to proceed? What is want for it to do is say while C is true return the area etc. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Java is a stronlgy typed language. In C(++) you get some automatic conversions between different buildin-types like `float` and `boolean`, so that any `float` not equal to 0 means `true`. Java does not allow those kind of conversions. One way (though very dirty) would be to rewrite your if-conditions:

```
[...]
if (0 != c)
{
    ...
}
[...]
```

This would emulate the C(++) semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to scan the initial input as String. Based on the input string try to perform the operation as follows:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Welcome to the round object calculator.\n This program will calculate the area       of a circle or the volume of a Sphere. \nEnter C for circle, S for sphere, or X t exit\n");

    String userInput = input.next();
    if ("C".equals(userInput)) {
        System.out.print("Enter radius of sphere: ");
        float radius = input.nextFloat();
    } else if ("S".equals(userInput)) {
        System.out.println("Sphere volume is : " + (4.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI
                * Math.pow(radius, 3));
        System.out.println("Sphere Surface Area is : " + 4.0 * Math.PI
                * Math.pow(radius, 3));
    } else if ("X".equals(userInput)) {
        System.out.println("End program");
    }
```

Comment: you will get complie time exception along the lines of "radius is not declared"

Comment: @Logan Murphy I havent posted the complete code above. Just posted the snipet where it can be useful. moreover in the actual program radius was defined above main method. private static final double radius = 0;

Comment: well then the issue is you dont set the static radius...you set the local radius inside the if...especially since the global static is final